# concatenate array and string variables in a php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is it possible to "glue" 2 variabels as one in a foreach? i've tried it with dot inbetween with array_combine. all give me errors...
the $courseFiles is an array, while the $block[id] is a int.

```
<?php
    foreach($courseFiles . $block["id"] as $courseFile): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($courseFile["Exercise Name"]) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($courseFile["Logsheet"]) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($courseFile["EBF Sheet"]) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: You cannot perform concatenation operation with an array.

Comment: For starters, you have a syntax error - you have a close parenthesis before `as`. What is the content of `$courseFiles[]`? What is the content of `$block[]`? ***What are you trying to achieve?***

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Are you having multiple vars `$courseFiles1`, `courseFiles2`, etc ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I deleted thatm but still no results... my guess is it can not be done. like Ravi says

Comment: gwendalm that is what i have yes

Comment: it basically is a foreach in a foreach where i need to use the value ( block variable) of the first foreach as a "counter" for the foreach inside the first for each... i can post the entire code if that makes it clearer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$myvar = array();
// assign values to $myvar array.
$myvar[$index] = $courseFiles[$index] . $block["id"]; 

foreach($myvar as $courseFile)
{ //some code }
```

Comment: that would work if both of them are strings/numbers, but $coursefiles is an array while $block is a number